# PL/SQL SELECT with multiple COUNT(DISTINCT xxx) - unexpected results

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, count, distinct

I'm trying to put together a query for an Oracle 11g application and I've run into a problem.

I'll simplify the real scenario to make it easier to understand (and also to protect the client's data):

- Table A is the base table. It has a known identifier in it that I pass in to the query.
- For each entry in Table A there may be multiple entries in Table B. Table B contains a value that I am interested in.
- For each entry in Table B there may also be multiple entries in Table C. Table C contains another value I'm interested in.
- I also have an XML snippet containing a list of values that may or may not match up to the values of interest in table C.
- The query does an outer join to the XML so that if there is a matching value it will return the value again, otherwise it is null.

What I want to do is get back the identifier I passed in, a count of the unique values in B and C, as well as a count of the unique (and non-null) values from the XML part of the join.

My current query is:

```
SELECT
    a.ID
  , COUNT(DISTINCT b.VAL) AS B_VAL
  , COUNT(DISTINCT c.VAL) AS C_VAL
  , COUNT(DISTINCT xml.VAL) AS XML_VAL
FROM a, b, c,
  XMLTABLE('/field1/collection/value' passing my_xml_type
    COLUMNS VAL VARCHAR2(50) PATH '.') xml
WHERE
      a.ID = b.SOME_ID
  AND b.OTHER_ID = c.OTHER_ID
  AND c.VAL = xml.VAL (+)
```

Now if you forget about the counting and just return rows, an example result set might look something like this:

```
ID     B_VAL     C_VAL     XML_VAL
---------------------------------------
X      abc       123       123
X      abc       456       null
X      abc       789       789
X      abc       789       789
```

**DESIRED:** Now when I want to do the distinct counts, I'd like it to return:

```
ID     B_VAL     C_VAL     XML_VAL
---------------------------------------
X      1         3         2
```

**ACTUAL:** However, this is what I'm getting when I have them all as COUNT(DISTINCT ...):

```
ID     B_VAL     C_VAL     XML_VAL
---------------------------------------
X      1         1         1
```

**ALTERNATIVE:** ...and if I take the DISTINCT out of the counts then I get:

```
ID     B_VAL     C_VAL     XML_VAL
---------------------------------------
X      1         4         3
```

How come the DISTINCT seems to be operating only within a particular B_VAL, but taking it out causes it to operate across all the rows but not taking uniqueness into account?

Is there another way of doing this that doesn't involve having to replicate all the joins as a sub-query? Have I missed the point entirely?

(Please note, I'm not a DB developer at all, I've just been pulled in to help out, so sorry if this is an easy problem... I HAVE searched Google and browsed this site for answers before posting, though!)

Thanks.

---

I've found that if I take the XML table join out then the count distinct works OK across the B_VAL and C_VAL... So perhaps it's something weird with how Oracle handles XML table joins?

Comment: Note, I've found that if I take the XML table join out then the count distinct works OK across the B_VAL and C_VAL... perhaps something weird with how Oracle handles XML table joins?

Comment: Given the answers below, what version of Oracle are you using? And does the test case given by Vincent also fail for you?

Comment: @MikeyByCrikey, I'm running 11.2.0.1 locally at the moment, and seeing different results to Vincent. Unfortunately even the nested query doesn't work for me. Besides, I need to find out the version of the target production database, I can't just patch my dev database...

Comment: Thanks for all the help, Alex and Vincent. It's definitely an Oracle bug of some sort. I'm unable to get the inner query working either, though, but I have another workaround - performing an entirely separate query to get the info I need. :( I wasn't expecting to be uncovering Oracle bugs in my first week of PL/SQL coding! :) I've marked Alex's post as the correct answer because of finding the bug reference, although thanks to both of you for your helpful responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Vincent's test case works in 10.2.0.3 and 11.2.0.2, and if you're at an earlier version of 11g, this could be bug 8816675: XMLexists query returns wrong results with a select DISTINCT. The example in the bug is referring to a problem with `count(distinct)`. You aren't explicitly using XMLexists, but the bug may have a wider impact then the title suggests, or it may be used under the hood.

If this is the problem, and you can't patch up, you might be able to work around it by wrapping the non-count version, which still isn't pretty:

```
SELECT
    A_ID
    , COUNT(DISTINCT B_VAL) AS B_VAL
    , COUNT(DISTINCT C_VAL) AS C_VAL
    , COUNT(DISTINCT XML_VAL) AS XML_VAL
FROM (
SELECT a.ID as A_ID, b.VAL as B_VAL, c.VAL as C_VAL, xml.VAL as XML_VAL
FROM a, b, c
    , XMLTABLE('/field1/collection/value' passing my_xml_type
        COLUMNS VAL VARCHAR2(50) PATH '.') xml
WHERE a.ID = b.SOME_ID
AND b.OTHER_ID = c.OTHER_ID
AND c.VAL = xml.VAL (+)
)
GROUP BY A_ID;
```

Comment: I think you're right in that it's a bug, given that the behaviour seems to be different in 11.2.0.1 (see my comment related to Vincent's post). Funnily enough, however, it doesn't work even when I do it as a sub-query! I still get X,1,1,1 as my values instead of X,1,3,2... There seem to be a bunch of other bugs relating to COUNT DISTINCT as well though that might be related (8714580 Wrong results from DISTINCT query with unnest of ANY subquery, 7661113 Query rewrite not working as expected with SELECT DISTINCT).

Comment: +1, nice catch :) @Chris: you might want to *materialize* the subquery by adding the `rownum` pseudo-column, this will force Oracle to take the additional step of running the subquery (instead of smartly merging it with the outer query)

Comment: @Vincent, I added ROWNUM to the inner query and still saw the same behaviour unfortunately. I even confirmed that the ROWNUM was being used by doing another test and counting the distinct number of rownums. If I take out the join to the XML, though, COUNT DISTINCT returns the right values across B, C (and ROWNUM when I include it), it's just losing the plot with the XML join. @Alex, you may well be right with the XMLexists bug!

Answer (score 4):

I can't reproduce your finding with Oracle 10.2.0.3.

Here's my setup:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE a AS SELECT 'X' ID FROM dual;

Table created

SQL> CREATE TABLE b AS SELECT 'abc' val, 'X' some_id, 1 other_id FROM dual;

Table created

SQL> CREATE TABLE c AS
  2     SELECT 1 other_id, '123' val,
  3            XMLTYPE('<field1>
  4                        <collection><value>123</value></collection>
  5                     </field1>') my_xml_type
  6       FROM dual UNION ALL
  7     SELECT 1 other_id, '456' val, NULL FROM dual UNION ALL
  8     SELECT 1 other_id, '789' val,
  9            XMLTYPE('<field1>
 10                        <collection><value>789</value></collection>
 11                        <collection><value>789</value></collection>
 12                     </field1>') my_xml_type
 13       FROM dual;

Table created
```

the query returns the right result:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2      a.ID
  3    , COUNT(DISTINCT b.VAL) AS B_VAL
  4    , COUNT(DISTINCT c.VAL) AS C_VAL
  5    , COUNT(DISTINCT xml.VAL) AS XML_VAL
  6  FROM a, b, c
  7     , XMLTABLE('/field1/collection/value' passing my_xml_type
  8                 COLUMNS VAL VARCHAR2(50) PATH '.') xml
  9  WHERE a.ID = b.SOME_ID
 10    AND b.OTHER_ID = c.OTHER_ID
 11    AND c.VAL = xml.VAL (+)
 12  GROUP BY a.id;

ID      B_VAL      C_VAL    XML_VAL
-- ---------- ---------- ----------
X           1          3          2
```

Can you run this test case?

Comment: With this test I get the right results in 11.2.0.2 (OTN Developer Days VM under VirtualBox) too.

Comment: When I run this locally under 11.2.0.1 I don't get this result... I get X, 1, 1, 1 as per my original post... Looks like it was a bug that was fixed... I'll need to check the remote database I'm actually developing against though, as I don't know which version it is. (Probably older...) I also need to find out what version the final production system will be running against!